# Passing a date/time value to touch command within bash function

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a bash function (Mac OS X) which searches for a specific range of files between two input date/times. Most variations I have tried for evaluating the two inputs `$1` and `$2` fail. Hardcoding the times works fine (as per usage line below) i.e. the search syntax is fine. Grateful for pointers where I'm going wrong on passing the two inputs to the touch commands.

```
function ffiles_search1 () {
echo "usage start 201911270000 end 201912102359 "
touch -t $(eval echo "$1")  /tmp/lower-date && touch -t $(eval echo "$2") /tmp/upper-date && find . -path "./Library" -prune -o  -type f -a -newer /tmp/lower-date -a ! -newer /tmp/upper-date -a -size +32k -a  ! -size +1024k -print0 | xargs -0 ls -ld | egrep -iv "|ppt|doc"
}
```

Comment: can you tell us what you try to pass as arguments (i.e. what is `$1` and `$2`)?

Comment: start time $1 is 201911270000  (0:00 on 27th November 2019 ) and end time $2 is 201912102359  (midnight on 10th December 2019).      So I am setting the time via touch on two temporary files as lower and upper date/times for the search

Comment: Unless you are trying to do odd things with whitespace `$(eval echo "$1")` is much better written as simply `"$1"`

Comment: The integers "204911270000" are not recognized as dates. (see `man touch`) but `2019-11-27 00:0000` is. Also, no need to do `eval echo "$1"` but `touch -t "$1"` :will do.

Comment: on my system touch -t 201912102359 filename   does work....

Comment: @kvantour : According to my touch man-page, the format for the `-t` argument is _[[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.ss] _, so the timestamp format looks reasonable to me.

Comment: @RichardL : You say that the coad _fails_. What does this mean?

Comment: @RichardL : In any case, if it works with hard-coded times, I suggest that you run it with `-x`, to see what is going on. Aside from your bizarre usage of `eval`, which WilliamPursell already pointed out, I don't see anything wrong, unless the parameters `$1` and `$2` have errnoeous values. Maybe it would make sense anyway to check these parameters for syntactic correctness and print a reasonable error message.

Comment: *Most variations I have tried for evaluating the two inputs $1 and $2 fail.* Please indicate what the failures are, specifically. Also show exactly how you called your script.

Comment: @user1934428 sorry, my mistake. I looked at the `-d` flag.

Comment: @user1934428    - yes you are right  re the eval,  I was in 'clutching at straws' mode having tried all the normal variants of "$1" etc.

Comment: Somewhat embarassingly (hands held up), reverting back to the usual "$1" and "$2" structure resulted in working code.  I am at a loss to explain why it failed first try.  Full working code below.  Thanks to all who assisted.

Comment: "Hands  held up", Yep, we've all been there. That mystery code, why didn't it work before!?  ... Glad you solved your problem, but please delete you final comment, as you have made it an answer and future readers will waste time trying to read it. (You can accept your own answer after 48? hrs, to gain more reputation points). Note that you can use the `{}` tool from the edit menu on mouse-selected text to format as `code/data/errMsgs`. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrected code,  invoking as

```
ffiles_search 201911270000 201912102359
```

on the function

```
function ffiles_search () {
    echo "usage start 201911270000 end 201912102359 " 
    touch -t "$1" /tmp/lower-date && 
    touch -t "$2" /tmp/upper-date && 
    find . -path "./Library" -prune -o -type f -a -newer /tmp/lower-date \
       -a ! -newer /tmp/upper-date -a -size +32k -a -size -1024k -print0 | 
    xargs -0 ls -ld |
    egrep -iv -f $HOME/Scripts/egrep_exclusions/time_search.txt 
}
```